# GitLab CI: "This job could not be executed because it would create an environment with an invalid parameter."

Tags: terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Two questions - see below for explanation:

1. How to set variables in Gitlab CI/CD to the output of a command?
2. How to make Gitlab CI/CD ignore the wrong error *"This job could not be executed because it would create an environment with an invalid parameter."*?

Explanation:

GitLab CI (on [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com)) refuses to automatically run a job. "Reason" shown:

> This job could not be executed because it would create an environment with an invalid parameter.

It should run the job automatically, whenever code is pushed. Despite that "error", the job runs flawlessly when I start it manually. This shows, that the error is wrong, I'd say.

The [repository](https://gitlab.com/alexs77/gitlab-terraform-test) is quite simple. Also the [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/alexs77/gitlab-terraform-test/-/blob/27b0a5a2c85a078264f725d316bd169a5f270ac8/.gitlab-ci.yml) file isn't so complex.

I *guess* that the error is triggered by [line 23](https://gitlab.com/alexs77/gitlab-terraform-test/-/blob/27b0a5a2c85a078264f725d316bd169a5f270ac8/.gitlab-ci.yml#L23):

```yaml
variables:
  # TF_STATE_NAME: default      # The name of the state file used by the GitLab Managed Terraform state backend
```

I do not set the "required" variable `TF_STATE_NAME` there. When I set the variable there, it works just fine.

But, actually, it is not so, that I do not set the variable. In fact, I set it — just not globally, but in each job. For example, [lines 42-45](https://gitlab.com/alexs77/gitlab-terraform-test/-/blob/27b0a5a2c85a078264f725d316bd169a5f270ac8/.gitlab-ci.yml#L42-45):

```yaml
.terraform:build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - export TF_STATE_NAME=$(awk '/zone_name/ {print $NF}' zone.auto.tfvars | tr -d \")
```

This reads the file [`zone.auto.tfvars`](https://gitlab.com/alexs77/gitlab-terraform-test/-/blob/27b0a5a2c85a078264f725d316bd169a5f270ac8/zone.auto.tfvars) and sets `TF_STATE_NAME` to its contents, basically.

For the given example, it would be: `TF_STATE_NAME=example`

At the end of the day, I'd need to set `TF_STATE_NAME` to output of some command (`awk …` in the example; could be anything). How do I do that?

And why is GitLab CI/CD so annoyed about `TF_STATE_NAME` being "unset" in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#create-a-dynamic-environment), you can create the name dynamically from a `dotenv` artifact with the current value of the environment name you want.

For your example it would be:

```yaml
variables:
  # the variable name must be set (empty is not allowed)
  TF_STATE_NAME: "to-be-erased"


# we se the TF_STATE_NAME in a variable in the dotenv file.
# this file is saved as an artifact.
.terraform:tf_state_name:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - TF_STATE_NAME=$(awk '/zone_name/ {print $NF}' zone.auto.tfvars | tr -d \")
    - echo "$TF_STATE_NAME" # for debugging in the CI
    - echo "TF_STATE_NAME=$TF_STATE_NAME" >> deploy.env
  resource_group: ${TF_STATE_NAME}
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: deploy.env


# The dotenv file is used for filling up the value of TF_STATE_NAME
.terraform:build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo ${TF_STATE_NAME}
    - gitlab-terraform plan
    - gitlab-terraform plan-json
  resource_group: ${TF_STATE_NAME}
  artifacts:
    # The next line, which disables public access to pipeline artifacts, may not be available everywhere.
    # See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactspublic
    public: false
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/plan.cache
    reports:
      terraform: ${TF_ROOT}/plan.json
      dotenv: deploy.env

tf_state_name:
  extends: .terraform:tf_state_name
  needs: []


build:
  extends: .terraform:build
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: prepare

stages:
  - validate
  - test
  - build
```

If you run this pipeline, the build job will be able to be launched and when run you'll see in the log:

```
$ echo ${TF_STATE_NAME}
example
```

and not `to-be-erased` the default value.

**edit**: add the variable with a default value.

Comment: thanks. will give it a try. why can't you test yourself? am i missing some information so that it can be easily tested? Doesn't seem to work, though. Probably mistake on my side. https://gitlab.com/alexs77/gitlab-terraform-test/-/blob/95be8c3197c1fd84c3f79a8c7c9b140acf990a52/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: In fact, I tested by fork your repo and I find a way to have a dynamic environment name. :-)